# Double RefreshIndicator for top&bottom of the list in Flutter with Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm making Flutter app with Flutter now.
The app concept is a SNS like Facebook.

When user turn on the app firt time, App will show a list of post with FutureBuilder.
This FutureBuilder has fetching process as "future" parameter and it will find the newest 5 posts at the first time.

Now I wanna add **refresh function with RefreshIndicator which works when user scroll the top of post list**.
With RefreshIndicator, I made a refresh function to find the post which created after the user open the app.
However, what about the old post which had been created before the 5 post which user got when the user turned on??
**How can I add one more refresh function with RefreshIndicator which can work when user scroll the bottom of post list?**

Please give me some tips about this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To detect if the user scrolls to the bottom of the ListView, you can add a listener to the ScrollController.

```dart
var _scrollController = ScrollController();

...

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _scrollController.addListener(() {
    if (_scrollController.position.atEdge) {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels == 0)
        debugPrint('Grid scroll at top');
      else {
        debugPrint('Grid scroll at bottom');
        
        // Scroll at the bottom, load more items on the List
        loadMore();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Then add the ScrollController on your ListView.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  controller: _scrollController,
  ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any Material widget for this situation rather than using controller??